# Plug unplug audio device events

Tags: c#

I am trying to get an event when an audio device is plugged or unplugged there are several questions asked for it but I am still not able to get

I was trying to use CoreAudio API I created ImmNotificationClient.cs interface

```
[Guid("7991EEC9-7E89-4D85-8390-6C703CEC60C0"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IMMNotificationClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Device State Changed
    /// </summary>
    void OnDeviceStateChanged([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string   deviceId, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] EDeviceState newState);

    /// <summary>
    /// Device Added
    /// </summary>
    void OnDeviceAdded([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwstrDeviceId);

    /// <summary>
    /// Device Removed
    /// </summary>
    void OnDeviceRemoved([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string deviceId);

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Device Changed
    /// </summary>
    void OnDefaultDeviceChanged(EDataFlow flow, ERole role, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string defaultDeviceId);

    /// <summary>
    /// Property Value Changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pwstrDeviceId"></param>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    void OnPropertyValueChanged([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwstrDeviceId, PropertyKey key);
}
```

I have created CMMNotificationClient.cs class which implements above methods

Now I am not sure How to register the call back to these methods and register for Plug and UnPlug Events

I tried to register it in the IMMDeviceEnumerator

```
[PreserveSig]
int RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient pClient);

[PreserveSig]
int UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(IMMNotificationClient pClient);
```

Can you please help on this or can you provide any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API to get notified.

[Stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245706/check-for-device-change-add-remove-events)

[CodeProject example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am looking for Audio device plug unplug like a headphone when done manually not the USB drive plu unplug Notification

Comment: I have already tried both the links earlier they work for USB drive and not for audio device like Headphone plug unplug

Comment: I think it depends on audio manufacturer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265101/event-headphone-jack-windows-xp-with-realtek-alc888 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861601/detecting-when-head-phones-are-plugged-in

Comment: I believe there is a solution to this using the Core Audio API as I am trying to use above but I did not find the exact solution

Comment: Can anyone help me on using OnDefaultDeviceChanged method using Core Audio API for this